# Creating an admin via update_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails. I want the existence of only one admin in my Rails application.

I followed this guide: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role
**Option 2: Adding an admin attribute**

I am stuck to this `current_user.update_attribute :admin, true`, I am not sure where should I run this command. I tried on the terminal but it does not work (it is a Rails commands, silly me) but I am not sure what to do with it.

I guess I have to create a new method like:

```
def update_to_admin
     current_user.update_attribute :admin, true
end
```

and the call `current_user.update_to_admin` somewhere

BUT (if I am right in this approach)

1) Where should I build this method? (I am using devise)

2) How can I use this method once I write it? From the terminal?

Comment: You would run that method in a rails console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would run that method in a rails console `rails c` on the terminal will open the console.

You will need to find your user or just grab the first one: `user = User.first`

Then update them: `user.update_attribute(:admin, true)`